# Relationship properties in 'Oracle SQL Developer Data Modeler'

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have four questions regarding to 'SQL Language' and 'Oracle SQL Developer Data Modeler':

1. What is the meaning of source optional or target optional in 'Oracle SQL Developer Data Modeler' relationships?

I it something related to'Ordinality' of the relationship?

Actually I make two different logical models. In the first one the source is optional, while in the second one the source is NOT optional.

**But the Generated DDL files for both of them are them same.** Why?

2. Why when we make a 1:N relationship, 'Identifying' in logical models, then the 'target optional' check box becomes DISABLED??
3. Why an M:N relationship can not be 'identifying' e.g. in M:N relationships the identifying check box is disabled?
4. What does 'in Arc' check box means in relation properties window?

Answer (score 1):

1. In 1:N relationship, the meaning of 'target optional' is that the corresponding attribute can be NULL (for example, a user exists without any subscriptions). I can't understand what the 'source optional' is in a 1:N relationship, in a relational model. However, in a ER-model, a source can be optional. Why not? Why can't you forbid a citizen to exist without a passport, for example? But I'm sure it can't be implemented in (forward engineered into) a pure relational model. However, it may be forward-engineered into some constraints (triggers, for example). I haven't ever tried that.
2. 'Identifying' actually means the foreign key (in the target) is a part of the primary key, so it can't be NULL. However, anyone decide to use surrogate keys instead, I think.
3. In a ER-model, the term 'Identifying relationship' isn't applicable for M:N relationships. At the worst, an M:N relationship can be treated as always-identifying. It may be confusing, because, in the corresponding relational model, an M:N will always be a table with two foreign keys, and if you imagine them like that then an M:N is always identifying for both foreign keys, but, of course, in a relational model, neither 'identifying' nor 'relationship' exist.
4. You can declare a super type for an entity (so it appears in a super type's rectangle and as well can or can not inherit its attributes). When you create a relationship from a super type to another entity, if the 'subtree generation' is set to 'table per child' for the source entity, the relation is forward-engineered into an arc. The arc means creation of foreign keys on the target table (one per the source's child type) and a constraint for each of the keys allowing non-null for only one of them.